# 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' followed by 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier'

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I am using a node server with express to use [Portis SDK](https://docs.portis.io/). The project structure looks like this :

```
├── app.js (entry)
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public (static files)
│   └── portis.js
└── views (templates and rendering)
    ├── home.html
    └── layouts
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "src",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "YYYYY",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "XXXXX",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@portis/web3": "^2.0.0-beta.59",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
    "pm2": "^4.5.0",
    "web3": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.2.0",
    "@types/web3": "1.0.18",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

in one of my templates (`home.html`),

```
<script src="/public/portis.js"></script>
```

and `portis.js` is the same as [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/portis-login-logout-production-xbqj1?file=/src/index.js).

When that template is served, I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (portis.js:1)
```

from searching SO results to solve it, when I change `home.html` and adding module type to the script:

```
<script type="module" src="/public/portis.js"></script>
```

(while `type="module"` is not used in codesanbox I copied from and it runs perfectly on that)

but it results in another error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@portis/web3". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

(If I remove `import "@portis/web3"` then it gives the same error on the next import line)

I have tried most of the relevant solutions which I found on SO but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try putting ...  type="text/javascript" in your script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `portis.js` is packaged as ESM (contains `export` clauses), then use `import Portis from './public/portis.js';`

Comment: can you elaborate on how to check if it's packaged as ESM?it works with node on that sandbox and I am trying to replicate it

Comment: Just check if there are `export` clauses inside, and that it doesn't `import` anything. By the way the sandbox you are referring to is a frontend that has a build process with ParcelJS (and you dont seem to have one)

Comment: I am trying to use that `index.js`(as portis.js) in my template, yeah I have not implemented ParcelJS, is there any way I could you that source code logic without ParcelJS?

Comment: It's not advised at all. I presume you are trying to use a file that has imports? You should use a build process in order to create a bundle with portis and all of its dependencies. Bundling tools also feature very interesting things like tree-shaking and minification. As an alternative, don't use ES modules, and add the UMD packaged file to your web app (it creates a global `Portis` object)

Comment: understood, I will switch to parcelJS, but as the documentation says I should be able to import modules after installing them via npm but ```TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@portis/web3". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".```. package is being considered as relative import

Comment: Indeed, that works in Node.js, or in browser applications built with Node.js, but not directly in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your import statements with

```
const Portis = require("@portis/web3");
const Web3 = require("web3");
```

Comment: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at portis.js:3
(anonymous) @ portis.js:3```